# How do I remove Koala?

Tags: software-center

Yesterday I installed Koala 64 bit version, the deb from the site. I'm not happy with it and want to remove it. I tried with the software-center, but that doesn't work. I can click on remove, but nothing is removed.

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If installed with a deb, like you said, then you should try:

```
sudo dpkg -r koala
```

Comment: Wow! The right answer within 30 minutes.  Great!